# Can oak server hook into deno's std serve server?

Tags: deno, oak

Given an existing native deno http server like this:

```
import {serve} from "https://deno.land/std@0.153.0/http/server.ts";
import { handle } from './astro/dist/server/entry.mjs';

serve((req: Request) => {
  console.log(req)
  return handle(req);
});
```

Is it possible to hook in [an `oak` app](https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0) where the console.log is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of Oak's [`Application`](https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/mod.ts?s=Application) class has a [`handle`](https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/mod.ts?s=Application#Properties) method for this purpose. From [the readme](https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/README.md?source#handle-method):

> #### `.handle()` method
>
> The `.handle()` method is used to process requests and receive responses without
> having the application manage the server aspect. This though is advanced usage
> and most users will want to use `.listen()`.
>
> The `.handle()` method accepts up to three arguments. The first being a
> [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) argument,
> and the second being a `Deno.Conn` argument. The third optional argument is a
> flag to indicate if the request was "secure" in the sense it originated from a
> TLS connection to the remote client. The method resolved with a
> [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object
> or `undefined` if the `ctx.respond === true`.
>
> An example:
>
> ```ts
> import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
>
> const app = new Application();
>
> app.use((ctx) => {
>   ctx.response.body = "Hello World!";
> });
>
> const listener = Deno.listen({ hostname: "localhost", port: 8000 });
>
> for await (const conn of listener) {
>   (async () => {
>     const requests = Deno.serveHttp(conn);
>     for await (const { request, respondWith } of requests) {
>       const response = await app.handle(request, conn);
>       if (response) {
>         respondWith(response);
>       }
>     }
>   });
> }
> ```

The example above uses Deno's low-level http API, so here's a contrived example to illustrate using it with the `serve` function from your question:

`./server.ts`:

```ts
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.153.0/http/server.ts";
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();

app.use((ctx) => {
  if (ctx.request.url.pathname === "/") {
    ctx.response.body = "You're at the root and this response came from Oak";
  } else ctx.respond = false;
});

await serve(async (request) => {
  const response = await app.handle(request);
  return response ??
    new Response("You're not at the root and Oak didn't return a response");
}, { hostname: "localhost", port: 8000 });
```